# Draw rectangle using mouse QML

Tags: qt, qml, waveform

I'm creating a wave form using QML 2.0.
I would like to know how I can draw rectangle starting when the user clicks on the waveform and ends when user releases mouse button.

I need something like the yellow rectangle.

I tried with Canvas but isn't working properly. 
Can you help me?

```
Canvas {
    property int prevX
    property int prevY
    property int hh:wave.height
    property int lineWidth: 2
    property color drawColor: "red"
    id:mycanvas

    height: 200
    width: 2000
    MouseArea {
        id:mousearea
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape:Qt.PointingHandCursor
        onPositionChanged: mycanvas.requestPaint();

        onPressed: {
            prevX = mouse.x;
            prevY = mouse.y
            var mousePosition = mouse.x / mousearea.width;
            wave.zoomOut(mousePosition);
            console.log("QML: ZoomStart mousePosition " + mousePosition)

        }

        onReleased: {
            var mousePosition = mouse.x / mousearea.width;
            console.log("QML: ZoomFinish mousePosition " + mousePosition)
            wave.zoomOut2(mousePosition);
        }
    }

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.05

        ctx.fillRect(prevX, 0, mousearea.mouseX-prevX,mainRectangle.height/4.5);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't it work properly? What does it do wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't run because of errors. Please post something that does.

Comment: @Mitch Is that you downvoting the newcoming QML questioners? ;)

Comment: @mlvljr, it sure is. I can only ask something so many times before I just start downvoting. That's what the feature is for, after all. At least I leave a reason though; most people on here just downvote and say nothing. :)

Comment: @Mitch You are one cruel pal, Mitch!

Comment: @mlvljr, why is it cruel?

Comment: @mlvljr, no, not really. Using the features of the site as intended is hardly cruel. I get downvoted if I ask a question with a major detail missing, why shouldn't others? Unless you have some reasoning behind it, let's leave the comments section for relevant comments. Post something on Meta if you disagree with me downvoting a question.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, this "new" SO where everyone is so polite is just nuts to my taste :) [this is the only thing I'll say]

Comment: @Mitch instead of downvoting you should help people. My question was clear enough for TheBootroo who gave me a great answer.

Comment: @dominic, I spend a great deal of time helping people who take the time to ask a decent question. Like I said, you didn't tell us what was going wrong and your code doesn't even run. If TheBootroo is happy taking the time to find the issue that you should have explained and fix the errors to actually run your example, good for him. I'd rather encourage people to ask questions that aren't just "here's a screenshot of what I want and my broken code, fix my problem".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is instanciate a QtQuick Rectangle dynamically and set its visual properties in the same time :

Just put this a a children of your 'wave graph' component :

```
MouseArea {
    id: selectArea;
    anchors.fill: parent;
    onPressed: {
        if (highlightItem !== null) {
            // if there is already a selection, delete it
            highlightItem.destroy (); 
        }
        // create a new rectangle at the wanted position
        highlightItem = highlightComponent.createObject (selectArea, {
            "x" : mouse.x 
        });
        // here you can add you zooming stuff if you want
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        // on move, update the width of rectangle
        highlightItem.width = (Math.abs (mouse.x - highlightItem.x));  
    }
    onReleased: {
        // here you can add you zooming stuff if you want
    }

    property Rectangle highlightItem : null;

    Component {
        id: highlightComponent;

        Rectangle {
            color: "yellow";
            opacity; 0.35;
            anchors {
                top: parent.top;
                bottom: parent.bottom;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the trick !

Comment: useful answer!! just tweaking to work in case you select from right to left instead of left to right!!

Comment: @Jimmy: would you mind to fix it in the posted code too? That would be helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the rectangle to be drawn even when the mouse drag position is not from left to right down. Hope it helps others.

```
Rectangle {

color: "transparent"

MouseArea {
    id: selectArea
    anchors.fill: parent

    property Rectangle highlightItem : null;
    property real startX
    property real startY

    onPressed: (mouse) => {
        if (highlightItem !== null) {
            // if there is already a selection, delete it
            highlightItem.destroy ();

        }
        // create a new rectangle at the wanted position
        highlightItem = highlightComponent.createObject (selectArea, {
            "x" : mouseX,
            "y" : mouseY,
        });
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;
    }
    onPositionChanged: (mouse) => {
       // on move, update the width of rectangle

       if (mouseX - startX < 0 ) {
           highlightItem.x = mouseX;
       }

       if (mouseY - startY < 0) {
           highlightItem.y = mouseY;
       }

       highlightItem.width = (Math.abs (mouseX - startX));
       highlightItem.height = (Math.abs (mouseY - startY));

    }
    onReleased: {

    }

    Component {
        id: highlightComponent;

        Rectangle {
            color: "#0D0080FF"
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "#fff"
        
        }
    }
}
}
```